# How to get an attribute named ID in gremlin

Tags: graph, groovy, gremlin

I'm getting weird results while writing a gremlin query. I can happily use the has function for most of the attributes for my nodes, for example "*().has('name', 'VerisignCzagExtension').property('id')" will return v5086. But when I attempt to use the has function with the attribute id it never returns true. for example "*().has('id', 'v5086').property('id')" returns no results. Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more details like the data store you are using (Neo4j, OrientDb, TinkerGraph, etc) with it's version? AFAIK, `id` is a reserved property and is usually numeric. Are you sure your `id` is not conflicting with an existing `id` property which is auto-incremented with each node/edge addition?

Comment: I'm using Neo4j 1.8 and I've been the id property within cypher queries, so I would assume that it hasn't been conflicting with anything in Neo4j. Although I have no idea if its conflicting with an id used by gremlin. Though if it is then the interesting part is that its still giving me the values that I supplied when I ask for the property. 

Perhaps a better question would be, given that it returns the right value from the property function, is there a similar function to has which would use the value returned by property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, Neo4j stores all IDs as `java.lang.Long` objects. This is a special behavior for `id` property only. All other properties are stored with their implied data types. That's a reason why `has('name', 'VerisignCzagExtension')` works (*because `name` property is excluded from this special behavior meant for `id`*). I'm assuming `v5086` is being type casted to `java.lang.Long`, thus losing it's real value. That could explain zero results after a `has('id', 'v5086')` Gremlin step.

AFAIK, `id` property is immutable (*can't be changed*). If you need to make `id` look ups for vertices using a `has` Gremlin step, it would look something like `has('id', 5086L)` assuming that the vertex `id` is `5086` and is being stored as a `java.lang.Long` value. An extra `L` is for explicit `java.lang.Long` type-casting, Neo4j would assume `java.lang.Integer` if you don't add that `L` and your Gremlin step would result in zero results again.

Finally, you might want to call your named ID something else, like a property with key `name`.

Hope this helps.