# Gremlin access a property "id"

Tags: groovy, graph, orientdb, gremlin

We use OrientDB and when using the Gremlin terminal, we cannot query for a single user id.

We have this

```
gremlin> g.V('@class','PERSON')[0..<5].map();
==>{id=50269488}
==>{id=55225663}
==>{id=6845786}
==>{id=55226938}
==>{id=55226723}
gremlin> g.V('@class','PERSON').has('id',50269488)[0..<5].map();
gremlin>
```

As you can see I tried filtering for that first id, but it doesn't return anything. I even tried typecasting to `50269488L` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029227/how-to-get-an-attribute-named-id-in-gremlin)

any tips what to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because property **id** is reserved somehow.
An example:

```
gremlin> g.V.id
==>#15:0
==>#15:1
...
```

This returns the RecordId instead of the property **id**.

---

From studio, e.g.:

```
create class PERSON extends V
create Property PERSON.id2 long
create vertex PERSON set id2 = 12345
```

Then this should work:

```
gremlin> g.V('@class','PERSON').has('id2',12345L)[0..<5].map();
==>{id2=12345}
```

**UPDATE:**

A workaround to this problem is to filter with **getProperty** method:

```
g.V('@class','PERSON').filter{it.getProperty("id")==12345}[0..<5].map();
```

Comment: Yeah this helps, but I knew the internal id is `@rid`. Not sure if there is a walk around.